# Either operating on a numeric value or replacing cell with nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

In a `pandas.DataFrame` df, let's say I have a column `E`.

If `E` contains an integer or float, I want to replace it everywhere with `10^6 * E`.

However if `E` contains non-numeric characters or simply whitespace, I want to replace it with np.nan.

Is there a simple way to do this with `apply` or `applymap` and a lambda function?

As a sanity check, doing this works on the numeric rows:

```
df['E'] = df['E'] *  1000000
```

This was syntactically correct but didn't change anything:

```
df['E'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000 if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else np.nan)
```

Maybe I have to do some casting, not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a lambda you can pass a function.  Something like this seems to work.

**Code:**

```
def times_million(a_number):
    try:
        return float(a_number) * 1000000
    except:
        return np.nan
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
    E
    1.0
    1
    xyzzy
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:], columns=data[0])

print(df['E'].apply(times_million))
```

**Results:**

```
0    1000000.0
1    1000000.0
2          NaN
Name: E, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Almost there... I made a small mod to your times_million function to add an explicit ValueError check because I had some strange values in some rows.
I see from the print statement that I do get the correct column now (of adjusted numbers mixed with NaNs) but the original df is not changed - any way to save it in-place in same statement?

Comment: Narrowing the scope of the exception may be desirable but *why* was it *necessary*?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't reading the output right.  It wasn't necessary to add ValueError.            I did this                                                                                   `df['E'] = df['E'].apply(times_million)`  to save it to the df.  Maybe all this was a little too much to ask of lambda.

Comment: Yes, all of the examples use lambda, so we tend to think lambda and try and cram too much into them.  Really no downside to defining a function.